# how to write a unit test case to verify the signatures?

Tags: java, mockito

I am very new to mockito , i want to write a unit test for a scenario where we are using a certificate to verify a signature 
my code is something like this ,

```
***public boolean messageSignatureValidation(SNSRequest snsRequest) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(snsRequest.getSigningCertURL());
            InputStream inStream = url.openStream();
            CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)cf.generateCertificate(inStream);
            inStream.close();
            Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
            sig.initVerify(cert.getPublicKey());
            sig.update(getMessageBytesToSign(snsRequest));
            return sig.verify(Base64.decodeBase64(snsRequest.getSignature()));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SIOInternalServerException(SIOErrors.SIO109500.toString(), "Signature verification failed");
        }
    }
    private static byte [] getMessageBytesToSign (SNSRequest snsRequest) {
        byte [] bytesToSign = null;
        if (snsRequest.getType().equals(NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE))
            bytesToSign = snsRequest.toString().getBytes();
        else if (snsRequest.getType().equals(SUBSCRIPTION_CONFIRMATION) || snsRequest.getType().equals(UNSUBSCRIBE_MESSAGE))
            bytesToSign = snsRequest.toString().getBytes();
        return bytesToSign;
    }***
```

I am trying to write the test case for messageSignatureValidation function how should i go about setting expectations for this method?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Your question is too broad. Keep in mind that it is up to you of what you want to test/check with the JUnit test you want to write. We cannot know what you want to test or what you want to check.

Comment: Well, the method should return true for a correctly signed request, and it should return false for an incorrectly signed request. So test those two cases.

Answer (score 0):

The basic purpose of unit Testing is to check that the business logic is working as expected in all possible scenarios.

And the objective while writing it should be to break the code as much as possible.

So, one should consider to provide all possible inputs and test the code's correctness. 
- Positive cases
- Negative cases
- Exception cases
- boundary conditions where the code is prone to break.
- Null Values , empty strings etc.
There must be testcases written for all possible flows in your business logic.
Here are few basics that you should cover-

```
    /*
 * testCase That checks happy scenario 
 */
@Test
public void testMessageSignatureValidationSuccess() throws Exception {

    SNSRequest snsRequest = new SNSRequest();
    snsRequest.setSignature("sampleTestinput");
    snsRequest.setType("type");
    snsRequest.setSigningCertURL("https://localhost:7077");
    boolean verify =messageSignatureValidation(snsRequest);
    assertTrue( verify);
```

}

```
/*
 * testCase That checks when validation fails 
 */
@Test
public void testMessageSignatureValidationFailed() throws Exception {

    SNSRequest snsRequest = new SNSRequest();
    snsRequest.setSignature("sampleTestinput");
    snsRequest.setType("type");
    snsRequest.setSigningCertURL("https://localhost:7077");
    boolean verify =messageSignatureValidation(snsRequest);
    assertFalse( verify);
```

}

```
/*
 * testCase That checks when validation throws error 
 */
@Test(expected = Exception.class)
public void testMessageSignatureValidationthrowsException() throws Exception {

    SNSRequest snsRequest = new SNSRequest();
    snsRequest.setSignature("sampleTestinput");
    snsRequest.setType("type");
    snsRequest.setSigningCertURL("https://localhost:7077");
    messageSignatureValidation(snsRequest);

}
```

Apart from this, if we go by your logic, there are 2 different flows based on the type of the `SnsRequest` object. So must  write test case for that cases as well.